# Nexus scripts doesn't return valid JSON

Tags: json, groovy, nexus, nexus3

### Context:

I'm using the [nexus scripting API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/script-api) to return some data. For some reason, returned data isn't JSON compliant. I am on nexus PRO 3.20.1-01. I'm not sure if this is a problem with Nexus or my script.

Here is a testable Groovy sample, deployable on nexus (the script is called `testScript.groovy`)

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput;

Map listOfValues = new HashMap<>();
HashSet<String> values = new HashSet<String>();
values.add('test1');
values.add('test2');
values.add('test3');

listOfValues.put('someValues',values);

Map<String, String> keyValues = new HashMap<>();
keyValues.put('firstKey','firstKey');
keyValues.put('secondKey','secondValue');

listOfValues.put('keyValues',keyValues);

result = JsonOutput.toJson(listOfValues);
return result;
```

(I know I don't need `;` in Groovy, but I can't do otherwise for the moment)

And I'm calling it with:

```
result=$(curl --noproxy $NO_PROXY --insecure -u $NEXUS_USERNAME:$NEXUS_PASSWORD -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' $NEXUS_SCRIPT_ENDPOINT/test/run)
echo 'result:'
echo $result
```

And the result (content of the http response) is:

> result: { "name" : "testScript", "result" :
>   "{\"keyValues\":{\"firstKey\":\"firstKey\",\"secondKey\":\"secondValue\"},\"someValues\":[\"test2\",\"test3\",\"test1\"]}"
>   }

---

### Problem:

There is 2 problems with this response:

First, all the escaped doubles quotes `\"` which makes this response non JSON compliant. I can still use `printf "$result"` to get rid of them. So the result would be:
result:

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "result" : "{"keyValues":{"firstKey":"firstKey","secondKey":"secondValue"},"someValues":["test2","test3","test1"]}"
}
```

Second, the value of result is always quoted, see `"result" : "{...}"` where it should be `"result" : {...}`. Which makes it not JSON compliant. It seems that the returned value is always interpreted as a Java/Groovy String. So I can't parse the html content as a JSON and do `result.keyValues.firstKey` for instance.

### Question:

Is there anyway to make the returned html response a valid JSON where I can parse the `result` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting an JSON encoded String inside JSON - so the output is expected and of course is valid JSON.

If whatever deals with your `result` from groovy is not able to JSON encode it itself (e.g. return `listOfValues` instead of `result`), you have to live with the response you get.  Decode the response once and then decode `response.result` again.

Comment: Ah yes, JsonOutput.toJson does return a String .... I've tried to return listOfValues, but result now contains the toString() of the map, which is even worse. I'll wait a litlle to see if someone has another solution, but I guess I'll have to parse the result.